# C++ Error C2040?

Tags: c++

Error Message:

What does this mean?

And how do I fix it?

error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char [2]'

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int round(double number);
//Assumes number >=0.
//Returns number rounded to the nearest integer.

int main()
{
    double doubleValue;
    char ans;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a double value: ";
        cin >> doubleValue;
        cout << "Rounded that number is " <<round(doubleValue)<< endl;
        cout << "Again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;

    }
    //Here is the line generating the problem, while(...);

    while (ans == 'y' || ans == "Y");

    cout << "End of testing.\n";

    return 0;
}

//Uses cmath
int round(double number)
{
    return static_cast<int>(floor(number + 0.5));
}
```

Comment: I saw the problem once you pointed out the line, but that is a very unhelpful compiler error message. It's not hard to see why people get frustrated with C and its ilk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to single-quote `char` literals.  You did this correctly for the first one but not the second:

```
while (ans == 'y' || ans == "Y");
```

This should be:

```
while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
```

Double quotes are for string (`const char[]`) literals.

Comment: Thank you, I need to start paying more attention to all small details in C++.

Comment: You could try this:  `while (toupper(ans) == 'Y');`

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes instead of single ones on this line:

```
while (ans == 'y' || ans == "Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

The capital Y is contained in double quotes, which creates a `const char [2]` (Y followed by null). You probably ment:

```
while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know this is useful or not but it may be like following:

while ((ans == 'y') || (ans == 'Y'));

Comment: The semi-colon is required because this is the end of a do-while-statement (instead of being a while-statement).