# C programming: IF statements

Tags: c, variables, int

I need help on a problem on C programming. I was wondering if there is a way to have a user input a word to the console and it would display whatever you program it to. Heres a example of what I want to do

```
int Choice;
int Energy = 100;
printf ("Type 2817!\n");
scanf ("%s", &Choice);

if(Choice == 2817)
{
    printf ("You have started the game\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
}
else if(Choice == "Energy") //This isnt working in my compiler.
                                //Apparently the == sign is the underlined error
{
    printf("%d", Energy);
}
```

So far I can only type numbers but I want to be able to type words and be able to use a command. SO basically I want to be able to type "Energy" and it will show the amount of energy you have (printf ("%d", Energy)

Please help,

Thank you for reading.

Comment: should be "`if(strstr(Choice,"2817") == 0`" in your code there...  `strstr` is the best way to look for a specific string within another string.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Only if "Choice" is a string ;-)

Comment: bah... I didn't notice "`Choice`" was an "`int`".  You're right!

Comment: choice should be a char array. char choice[100], or something that fits the bill

Comment: words are strings in C. Learn about the functions in `string.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your program is trying to do, but let me concentrate on the few obviously incorrect lines.

First, in

```
int Choice;
scanf ("%s", &Choice);
```

you have the wrong type for Choice: it is "int" whereas it should be a static array of char (let's say char Choice[32]). In this case you also have to remove the "&" before "Choice" in the scant, so that the code becomes:

```
char Choice[32];
scanf ("%s", Choice);
```

Moreover, in

```
else if(Choice == "Energy") //This isnt working in my compiler.
```

you are trying to compare two strings with the operator "==". This does not work in C. You should use the function "strcmp" the following way:

```
#include<string.h>
[...]
else if(strcmp(Choice, "Energy")==0)
```

You'd even better use the following to prevent any buffer overflow

```
else if(strncmp(Choice, "Energy", 32)==0)
```

(replace 32 with the maximum number of elements in Choice)

**Edit** Note that you should change the first comparison too from

```
if(Choice == 2817)
```

to

```
if(strncmp(Choice, "2817", 32))
```

because Choice is not an int anymore...

Comment: else if(strncmp(Choice, "Energy", 32)==0) { printf ("Hi"); } It is underlining the "Choice" part of the code. Im not sure why it is a error. Here is the error:error C2040: 'Choice' : 'char [32]' differs in levels of indirection from 'int' –

Comment: Could you show me the exact error message please ? When I try, I get an error on the "if(Choice==2817)" instead. This one should be fixed by using strncmp(Choice, "2817", 32) instead

Comment: texttest1.cpp(29): error C2040: 'Choice' : 'char [32]' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

Comment: OK, judging from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991019/c-error-c2040 you may be using a C++ compiler. Therefore you should replace double quotes by single ones. That is, "Energy" becomes 'Energy'.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Ive been trying to figure that out for so long. I think it works now. I have no errors so it should be able to work. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I would suggest you to mark my answer as "correct answer" in order to close the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You have enter wrong datatype when comparing the choice (int type) with a string text. In C/C++ unlike dynamic programming language, you cannot compare int with strings without properly converting either of them. You use strcpy for comparing string and == for comparing int.

Then your programming will run.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this problem would to be to make `Choice` a string, then compare it to string values, or extract data from the string (for example with `atoi`) and assign it to other variables. C is a statically typed programming language, an `int` cannot become (or be compared to) a string because they are not of the same type. If you want arbitrary data from the user, the best way to approach that problem is probably to use a string. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Read your input as array of chars
example

`char bleh[250];
    scanf ("%s", bleh);//or scanf ("%s", &bleh[0]);`

and then use strcmp command to compare two arrays

`strcmp(&bleh[0], "blabla"); //function will return 0 if two arrays match`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

"String" is `const char *`, you cannot compare using **==** in C++. You need to use **strcmp** to compare string.

`strcmp` returns zero if strings are same.

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes in the code.

1. use `strcmp()` to compare string.
2. Declare `int Choice;` to `char Choice[50]`
3. Remove `&` while reading string in scanf()
4. Comparing with if(Choice == 2817) is not correct. use `if(strcmp(Choice , "2817") == 0)`

Comment: else if(strncmp(Choice, "Energy", 32)==0)
 {
  printf ("Hi");
 }

It is underlining the "Choice" part of the code. Im not sure why it is a error. Here is the error:error C2040: 'Choice' : 'char [32]' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'